# Detect duplicate keys in JSON using php

Tags: php, json, validation, duplicates

I am receiving a JSON string from an external partner and parsing it using php 5.3.3

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonString);
json_last_error()...
```

While json_last_error() detects invalid JSON it does not detect duplicate keys as in:

```
{
  "first" : "First name",
  "last"  : "Last name",
  "info"  : {
     "phone" : "555-555-555",
     "phone" : "222-222-222"
     }
}
```

Note that the two phone numbers use the same key and are not in an array. 
Is there a way to detect such duplicate keys in php?

Answer (score 3):

There **cannot** be a duplicate key!

That is the definition of a **key** -- it must be *unique*.

The second one will overwrite the first one, therefore there **won't** be any real duplicate key.

Comment: Yes. There should be no duplicate keys. Unfortunately, I sometimes receive invalid JSON from external partners that DO have duplicate keys. json_last_error() does not detect it because, as you correctly stated, json_decode() uses the last one. So how do I detect such an issue when it exists in a JSON I receive from the outside?

Comment: @iRadio you cannot unless you build your own json parser.

Comment: Thanks Neal. Sorry to hear that, but appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 3):

As @Neal said, this is not possible unless you build your own json parser. Or use someone else's.

For instance, you can use [seld/jsonlint](https://packagist.org/packages/seld/jsonlint).

Here is the code [Composer uses since today to warn about duplicate requirements](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/e87190e3da7758023cbcb7c7f4e63530e3866884).

```
<?php
$jsonParser = new JsonParser;
try {
    $jsonParser->parse(file_get_contents($localConfig), JsonParser::DETECT_KEY_CONFLICTS);
} catch (\Seld\JsonLint\DuplicateKeyException $e) {
    $details = $e->getDetails();
    $io->writeError('<warning>Key '.$details['key'].' is a duplicate in '.$localConfig.' at line '.$details['line'].'</warning>');
}
```